# The full output is not being printed

Tags: c

im not getting an output for this program, please help
THE QUESTION:
Twin primes are consecutive odd numbers both of which are prime numbers. Write a program which inputs two positive integers A and B and outputs all twin primes in range A to B.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num1,num2,temp,i,p1,p2;
    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    p1=0;
    p2=0;
    printf("Twin prime numbers are:");
    if(num1>num2){
        temp=num1;
        for(i=num2;i<temp;i=i+1){
            int j;
            for(j=2;j<i;j=j+1){
                if(i%j!=0){
                    p1=1;
                }
            }
            int k;
            for(k=2;k<(i+2);k=k+1){
                if((i+2)%k!=0){
                    p2=1;
                }
            }
            if(p1==1 && p2==1 && (i+2)<=num2){
                printf("\n%d and %d",i,i+2);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        temp=num2;
        for(i=num1;i<temp;i=i+1){
            int j;
            for(j=2;j<i;j=j+1){
                if(i%j==0){
                    p1=1;
                }
            }
            int k;
            for(k=2;k<(i+2);k=k+1){
                if((i+2)%k==0){
                    p2=1;
                }
            }
            if(p1==1 && p2==1 && (i+2)<=num1){
                printf("\n%d and %d",i,i+2);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\shaun\OneDrive\Desktop> cd "c:\Users\shaun\OneDrive\Desktop\c programming\programs\" ; if ($?) { gcc twin_primes.c -o twin_primes } ; if ($?) { .\twin_primes }
Enter 2 numbers: 8 19
Twin prime numbers are:
PS C:\Users\shaun\OneDrive\Desktop\c programming\programs>
```

Comment: Did you try a debugger? Give it small inputs and trace step by step.

Comment: @EugeneSh. ill try debugging, but i request you to also check on your end.

Comment: Suggestion: `if (num1 > num2) swap(&num1, &num2); /* now work with the knowledge that num1 <= num2 and don't duplicate code */`

Comment: @shaun, you get to ask a question.  You **do not** get to ask us to take any particular action.

Comment: The question of where the error(s) in the program may be aside, the approach it takes is flat awful.  Just how many times do you think you should need to compute the same list of primes?  Hint: once should be sufficient.  If this is for a challenge problem where the upper bound on the inputs is large, and the program must complete in a short time, then you should throw the whole thing away and start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

```
if(p1==1 && p2==1 && (i+2)<=num2)
if(p1==1 && p2==1 && (i+2)<=num1)
```

You've mixed up with num2 & num1 in above 2 conditions.

If you use `num1` instead of `num2` and `num2` instead of `num1`, you'll get the output.

---

Apart from this, there're several logical errors in code.

1. Logic to find prime number
2. Initializing variable `p1` and `p2` in proper place

To solve above 2 problems, I would recommend to learn more about finding prime numbers. I'll add some resources at below, please check those.

---

Another thing, you're basically writing same code twice. You could make it more simple by just swapping 2 given values when first one is larger than the second one.

---

Lastly, I'm giving a sample code here. It's one of the way you could follow to write simple but easily understandable solution for your problem.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool isPrime(int num)
{
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int num1,num2,temp,i,p1,p2;
    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    p1=0;
    p2=0;
    printf("Twin prime numbers are:");
    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        // swap the numbers. always keeping the first as the smaller one
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }

    if (num1 == 1) num1++;  // ignoring 1

    for(int i = num1; i <= num2 - 2; i++)   // running the loop till num2 - 2, so we won't have to check whether i + 2 <= num2
    {
        if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(i+2))
        {
            printf("\n%d and %d",i,i+2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please check below URLs to learn more about prime number and swapping values

- [C Program to Swap Two Numbers](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/swapping)
- [C Program to Swap two Numbers GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-swap-two-numbers/)
- [Prime Numbers GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-numbers/)
- [C Program to Check Whether a Number is Prime or Not](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/prime-number)
- [Which is the most efficient way to calculate prime numbers in C?
  Quora](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-calculate-prime-numbers-in-C)

Comment: Habib Thanks a lot

Comment: You're always welcome